# Infeasible and Feasible solution of polyhedron

Tags: optimization

Let $P:= \{Ax = b, x \geq 0\} $ be a polyhedron in standard form, where
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
\end{bmatrix} \text{ and }  b = \begin{bmatrix}
4 \\ 18 \\ 10
\end{bmatrix}$$
Find two infeasible basic solutions and two basic feasible solutions of $P.$

I know that for a infeasible basic solution, the solution has to contain a negative (is this true in general?) so considering
$B_1 = \begin{bmatrix} A_3 & A_1 &A_5 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B_2 = \begin{bmatrix} A_2 & A_4 & A_5 \end{bmatrix}$ gives the respective solutions $$x_{B_1} =  B_1^{-1}b= \begin{bmatrix} 9 & 0 &-5 & 0 & 10 \end{bmatrix}^T$$ and $$x_{B_2} =  B_2^{-1}b= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 & 0 & 20 & 12 \end{bmatrix}^T$$ which are the infeasible basic solutions. I am having hard time using this same approach to find a basic feasible solution such that the solution $x\geq 0.$ What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: use the two-phase method (or enumerate all 6-choose-3 combinations, it's really not that many)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$B_3 = \begin{bmatrix} A_3 & A_4 & A_5 \end{bmatrix} = I_3$$ and
$$B_4 = \begin{bmatrix} A_2 & A_3 & A_4 \end{bmatrix} $$
to obtain the basic feasible solutions
$$x_{B_3} =  B_3^{-1}b= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 &4 & 18 & 10 \end{bmatrix}^T$$ and
$$x_{B_4} =  B_4^{-1}b= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 10 &24 & 8 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T.$$
Since $x \geq 0,$ we have a basic feasible solution.